# Issue with Wizcorp phonegap facebook plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

We are trying to integrate the Wizcorp PhoneGap facebook plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) to support the login process in a new Ionic app.

The login with Facebook seems to work just fine for a new user. The problem is when the users sign off and try to log back in he get the error:

> Facebook error: Session was closed and not closed normally

what are we doing wrong here ?

Here's the code that we are using right now:

```
function fbLogin() {
  facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email'], function (response) {
    alert("Login Successfull");
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  }, function (error) {
    alert("Login ERROR");
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  })
}

function getDetails() {
  facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      alert("You're connected!");
      var userID = response.authResponse.userID;
      facebookConnectPlugin.api('/' + response.authResponse.userID + '?fields=id,name,picture.width(400).height(400)', [], function (result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      })
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      alert("Not Autherized!");
    } else {
      alert("You're not loggin into Facebook!");
    }
  });
}

function fbLogout() {
  facebookConnectPlugin.logout(function (response) {
    alert("Logout success");
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  }, function (error) {
    alert("Logout ERROR");
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  })
}
```

We have checked this link:

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#no-reply-from-login

however when we try to implement the code below - we get an error

> Tyeperror cordova.getActivity is not a function

```
PackageInfo info = cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.goapes.golearn", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
```

The above link tells us that we need another Hash Key in our Facebook App Dashboard, so is there another way of obtaining this Hash?

Answer (score 0):

I think you better to try this plugin. Because I developed a app using this plugin and it's in production now. :)
here [check this](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4)

Comment: Hi Shanaka - the plugin looks promising, we have however found another solution for this - anyway, thanks for the reply.